# How can I sync folders stored within WSL2 to VirtualBox guest?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, wsl2

I have switched from WSL1 to WSL2 and moved my project files inside WSL2 as is recommended for performance reasons. I have VirtualBox installed on the Windows side (CentOS 7 guest) and Vagrant installed in WSL2 with the appropriate exports in place to have them talk to each other. I have even got around the networking issues but I just *can't* figure out how to get the vagrant file syncing working in WSL2 when the files now reside here.

When I vagrant up, I get an error that this is not supported because the files are within WSL2 and not a DrvFs mount:

```
The host path of the shared folder is not supported from WSL. Host path of the shared folder must be located on a file system with DrvFs type.
```

**Short of moving the files back over to the Windows side, how can I get this to work?**

I tried the SMB type, but get:

`It appears your machine doesn't support SMB`

I find that hard to believe given the host is Windows. Samba/cifs-utils also installed in guest.

NFS type gives a similar error:

`It appears your machine doesn't support NFS`

Here I tried the vagrant nfs plugin which didn't work either.

The rsync type works, but isn't a great solution and kept prompting me for the vagrant user password every time it ran.

I have gone back to WSL1 again now until this last bit can be figured out.

Comment: Have you tried to mount the shared folder within WSL? SMBv1 by default is turned off on Windows 10 hosts.  You might verify it is enabled or configure Samba to explicitly use SMBv3

Comment: The folder is already within WSL2. I did try to `mount -t drvfs '//wsl$/ubuntu/home/projects/foo' '/mnt/foo'` and reference `/mnt/foo` in my Vagrantfile, but this errored as it was trying to resolve a mangled looking path it could not find.

Comment: What isn't clear is the operating system of the VM.

Comment: It's CentOS 7. I have updated my question. I also just tried to force the use of SMB version 2 or 3 by specifying `mount_options: ['vers=3.0']` but still get the SMB is not supported error.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a symlink from the directory in WSL2 to the 9P mounted Windows directory and configuring vagrant to go via the symlink works:

`ln -s /home/jamie/projects /mnt/d/projects`

`config.vm.synced_folder "/mnt/d/projects/foo", "/var/www" ...`

Answer (score 0):

- Host OS: Windows 11 Pro 22H2
- VirtualBox: 6.1.40
- Vagrant (Host/WSL): 2.2.19
- Guest OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (*via WSL2*)

Had the same issue, trying to mount DrvFs with NFS.
Symlinks won't work either.

After all, standard synced folder (no NFS/no SMB) worked for me:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: false
```

Then, to tweak permissions of mounted directory inside Ubuntu I'm using [BindFS](https://bindfs.org/):

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-bindfs
```

and specify options inside your **Vagrantfile**:

```
# https://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs-help.txt
config.bindfs.bind_folder "/vagrant", "/var/www/myproject",
    u: "vagrant",
    g: "www-data",
    p: "0774",
    chown_ignore: true,
    chgrp_ignore: true,
    chmod_ignore: true
```

Works without problems in both directions.

Comment: Question is about WSL